# How can I change the className of an element on click? (hamburger menu)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a hamburger menu, on click I want the 'mobile view hamburger' to drop down (go from display: flex to display: initial). Seems that I can't get the js to work..

I'm totally new to JavaScript and React, could someone explain what's missing?

The html which is returned and exported from the function Nav and rendered in App.js:

```
      <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-brand">
        <NavLink to="/" exact>
          <img className="logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/KnEvuRJ.png"></img>
        </NavLink>

      </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link Navbar__Link-toggle">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </div>

      <nav class="Navbar__Items">
        <div class="Navbar__Link">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/" exact activeClassName="active">
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about" activeClassName="active">
            About
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/chars" activeClassName="active">
            Characters
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="Navbar__Link">
          <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/login" activeClassName="active">
            Login
          </NavLink>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

The js code to toggle:

```
  function classToggle() {
    const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.Navbar__Items')

    navs.forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('Navbar__ToggleShow'));
  }

  document.querySelector('.Navbar__Link-toggle')
  .addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

The css: ( inside @media..)

```
.Navbar__Link-toggle {
    align-self: flex-end;
    display: initial;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Why would you do something like this? This just hurts my eyes. You're using react and still using vanilla code to handle your components. I suggest you study up some more about react before tackling these problems.

Comment: In react, the recommended approach would be to use states as class rather than manipulating DOM classes with above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how `React` works, there is absolutely no need to use vanilla js here. What about binding the class toggle behavior with a `state`'s property ?

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    state = {
        isButtonToggled: false
    }

    handleClick = () => this.setState({isButtonToggled : !this.state.isButtonToggled})

    render(){
        const { isButtonToggled } = this.state
        const buttonStyle = classnames({
            ['button-root'] : true,
            ['button-toggled'] : isButtonToggled
        })

        return(
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} className={buttonStyle}>Click</button>
        )
    }
}
```